# Wordpress wp_query orderby not working

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying to get ordering working in wp_query, but posts are still being ordered with default settings (just tag__in is working). SQL query for posts looks like this:

```
string(379) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (81) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3"
```

Here is code snippet:

```
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
$tag = get_term_by('name', 'title_post', 'post_tag');
$args=array(
            'order'=>'ID',
            'orderby'=>'ASC',
            'tag__in' => $tag,
            'posts_per_page'=>3, // Number of related posts to display.
            'caller_get_posts'=>1
);

$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
var_dump($my_query->request);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I switched order and orderby ... 
So, correct arguments are 'orderby'=>'ID','order'=>'ASC',

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code you have to pass wrong arguments.

Can you please check below code?

**Wrong**

```
'order'=>'ID',
'orderby'=>'ASC',
```

**Right**

```
'order'=>'ASC',
'orderby'=>'ID',
```